# Search the special line in file text file and return the seperate content the file in C#

Tags: c#

I have the text file for example `abc.txt` and I want to separate the information of every object in this file into the List.
For example, in the file I have 30 objects, I need to store in List of 30 elements.

Example for objects is given below ( object1: from line 4-14, object2: from line 15-25)

**Contents of the sample text file**

```
RenderLight table:
HatchPattern table:
ModelGeometry table:
    //Object 1:
    ModelGeometry 0:
        Model component 61
            Model serial number = unset         
        Attributes:
            object name = "449455275"
            object uuid = 3184E1B4-9EF8-11e8-8495-0A08D7624070          
            material source = layer material
        Geometry:
            ON_PolylineCurve:  domain = [0,4]
              point[ 0] = (400.48911333386786, 343.17690910026431, 0), 0             
              point[ 4] = (250.34888901072554, 2.7775950077921152, 0), 4
    //Object 2:
    ModelGeometry 1:
        Model component 62
            Model serial number = unset
        Attributes:
            object name = "216959248"
            object uuid = 3184E1B5-9EF8-11e8-8495-0A08D7624070
            material source = layer material
        Geometry:
            ON_PolylineCurve:  domain = [0,1]
              point[ 0] = (5.7191539468476549, 0.49928491655737162, 0), 0
              point[ 1] = (84.328223334276117, 17.490530318580568, 0), 1
HistoryRecord table:
User data table:
```

**This is the code used to retrieve the required element:**

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
{
     if(ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
     {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
        {
             textBox.Clear(); //textBox mean the name of the FormText
             textBox.Text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
             string searchKeyword = "ModelGeomety" & " " & "???" ;
             string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
             List<string> results = new List<string>();
             foreach (string line in textLines)
             {
                  if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                  {                        
                        results.Add(line);
                  }
             }
        }
     }
}
```

The input is the text file, and the output is two objects that are saved in a List or separate file or some type of data structure.

Comment: This looks like YAML.  Why not just use a YAML Serializer?

Comment: can it use in C#?

Comment: Just google YAML C#, [here is the first result](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet)